# Had a great(?) phone interview and was told I would hear back...haven't. What to do next?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up, phone

I had a phone interview on Tuesday of last week for a company that I'm very interested in. The initial screening went so well that she wanted me to speak with the Director of the department I was applying to as soon as possible, so I ended up having two phone interviews that afternoon. I'm not sure how the second one went. It was very short and he only asked one question, although I had a few for him and he had said "that's a great question" to two of them. At the end of the call he told me he would have the initial interviewer contact me. I was foolish in not asking when. I sent both interviewers a thank you email and said I was excited to learn about the next steps but I haven't heard anything back.

How long should I wait to follow up since it was only a phone screening and what is the best way to follow up? I'm not sure if the 10 day rule applies here or if I should be more proactive. Like I said, I'm VERY interested in this job but they were vague on their timeline (initial interviewer's response was that she hoped to make a decision soon - wouldn't specify a date).

Answer (score 1):

It's been less than a week; there's lots of reasons things can get delayed. Perhaps they're waiting for someone in HR to return from vacation so they can put together an official offer letter; perhaps they're trying to interview a second person who wasn't available last week; perhaps they had an all-hands-on-deck emergency and everything non-essential got put down until it was solved.

In any case, without any insight into what's happening, your best bet is to put that job out of your mind and move on for now. If they contact you today, then you haven't lost anything, but if they never get back with you at all, you don't want to waste too much time and miss other potential opportunities while you sit by the phone.